# Is there a jump list control in WinRT like Windows Phone?

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I do want this control in sometime for my project. For ex, I want it to be displayed when my app in snap mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use semantic zoom for that purpose.

[Guidelines for Semantic Zoom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/hh465319.aspx)

[XAML GridView grouping and SemanticZoom sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/GroupedGridView-77c59e8e)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented jumplist using semantic zoom. Might blog about it if anyone's interested.